# 2D Sprite を Compressed フォーマットにすると透過する

Tags: unity3d

PNG 画像のアトラスを Sprite Editor で切り出して Sprite として使用し、 Format を Compressed 設定にすると、元々透過がなかった画像が透過してしまい、うっすらと背景が見えてしまいます。 Format を TrueColor に設定すると、透過しなくなります。

同様の現象を経験された方はいらっしゃいますでしょうか。 またその場合同様の状態から Compressed 設定で透過しなくする設定、方法等ありましたら、ご教示いただけると幸いです。

環境は以下になります。

- Unity 4.6.2 Pro
- Windows 7

画像ファイルは Photoshop で "*Web 用に保存 → PNG-24 / 透明部分にチェック*" で出力しています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

これと同じ現象でしょうか。
http://tsubakit1.hateblo.jp/entry/2014/12/26/233000

もしそうなら以下の操作で治るかもしれません。

- Use Direct11のチェックを外す

Answer (score 1):

圧縮テクスチャー(Compressed)はピクセルの値が多少変化するので、フォトショップで不透明度付きで出力した場合、オリジナルのピクセルが完全不透明(α=1)でも実際に表示されるときは１以下になる可能性はありますね。
やってみて変化したならあきらめるしかないです。